# Löwenheim-Skolem and proper class models of ZFC.

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

> Let $N$ be a proper class model of ZFC and $x \subset N$ a set. Show that  there is a set $y \in N$ such that $x \subset y$.

If $x \subset N$, I think that by the downward's part of Löwenheim-Skolem, we can find an elementary submodel $y$ of $N$ such that $x \subset y$. But how would I conclude that $y \in N$? It seems like I'm missing something trivial but I can't figure out what exactly.

**Note:** A hint to point me to the right direction would be more appreciated than a complete answer.

Comment: Use foundation.

Comment: (And you cannot use the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem.)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Thanks! I'll try. Small question: why cannot we use LST for proper classes?

Comment: @CarlMummert I made I mistake while typing. We are trying to show that there is a set $y \in N$ such that $x \subset y$. Also, the question means that $(N,\in)$ is a model of ZFC, or at least that's how I interpret it. Hope this clarifies some stuff.

Comment: Is $x\subset y$ in the claim meant to be evaluated with the model's $\in$ relation? Or is the model implicitly supposed to be standard?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think so, yes. Maybe I am missing some context but I would say that $x \subset y$ has to be evaluated with the $\in$ relation.

Comment: If we could use the LS theorem like this for proper classes, then we could prove the consistency of ZFC. Instead we have reflection theorems, which have a somewhat smaller scope than 'elementary submodel'.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I think I haven't done much progress though. Using the Reflection Principle, for each $x \subset N$ I can pick a transitive set $y$ with $x \subset y$ and such that $y$ reflects foundation. But how can I go from here to the claim in the problem? Thank you.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks for the comment! I didn't thought about using the Reflection Principles!

Comment: @user313212 I was just explaining how to see LS doesn’t apply for proper classes, not so much suggesting the use of reflection theorem in this particular problem. I think what Andres was suggesting was to take $y$ to be $N$’s version of $V_\alpha$ for some sufficiently large $\alpha.$ Similar to Henning’s suggestion below for $H_\kappa.$

Comment: @user313212 I think that properly addressing the issue of why Lowenheim-Skolem doesn't apply deserves some room. Why don't you ask about it as a separate question? In particular, it may help clarify the relation between the reflection theorem and your suggested approach.

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality $x$ is transitive, at least relative to $N$ (that is, $\bigcup x\cap N\subseteq x$).

Because $N$ is a *proper* class model, it contains elements of arbitrarily large cardinalities. In particular it contains a cardinal number $\kappa$ that does not inject into $x$ at the metalevel, and therefore cannot inject into any subclass of $x$ in $N$.

But then $N$'s $H_\kappa$ must contain all of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight twist on Henning's answer:

Fix, working in $V$, an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $x \subseteq V_{\alpha}$. By the absoluteness of $\mathrm{rank}_{\in}$, we have $V^N_\alpha = V_\alpha \cap N$ and hence 
$$y = x \cap N \subseteq V_{\alpha} \cap N = V^N_\alpha.$$